# How to change process name objective-c

Tags: objective-c, c

I have a Objective-C command line tool that I am forking. I need to change the name of the forked process. I have no code to show because I don't have an idea where to start.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217947/setting-process-name-on-mac-os-x-at-runtime

Answer (score 2):

One idea that comes to mind would be suspending all threads in the process and making a new process with a different name and the exact same registers, threads, stacks, heap etc etc.

Comment: How would you go about naming the new process?

Comment: @735Tesla I would make a new .exe file that does nothing but has the desired process name, have the program that changes process names run the new .exe file, then suspend it, then start editing the process until it's an exact copy of the process you wanted to rename then abruptly terminate the process you wanted to rename.